# Dataset not reflecting changes after applying lambda function, how to commit changes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

[I want to save this dataset exactly in this given image format, i have tried saving it with to csv function but this does not seem to work outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFBTL.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just do : data = data.groupby(..)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [pandas groupby docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the method returns a `GroupBy Object`; so in order to store it, you have to give it to a variable:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(.....)
```